# WPF: xmldataprovider access database

Tags: xml, database, vb.net, ms-access, data-binding

Is it possible to bind my access database in here?

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="DeviceListData" XPath="Root">
        <x:XData>
            <Root xmlns="">

                <Entry Name="{Binding}" Image="{Binding}" />     
            </Root>
        </x:XData>
    </XmlDataProvider>
```

If yes. how?
I used to use ItemSource for controls, but in here, i don't know how.
Please Help me. Thanks.

Comment: An Access database is not an XML data source, so what would be the point of this exercise?

Comment: I'm just wondering if the data in access DB can be binded to xml's data.